# set cookie before log out and after admin login

Tags: wordpress, session, cookies, admin

Hi I am new to wordpress.

I had researched lot about this but didn't succeed. I want to set cookie value NULL before logout and custom value after admin logged in.

So I put below code in wp-includes/puggable.php => in the function wp_set_auth_cookie

`setcookie("cookieName", '', time() + (1 * 60) , true);`

`echo "<script>console.log('Cookie must set null')</script>";`

But didn't get succeed cookie value remain same even after login-logout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NEVER** edit Wordpress core files! If you update Wordpress one day (and you'll want to, as to fix the security issues), all your modifications will be lost.

What you need to do is to work with the [`wp_login`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) and [`wp_logout`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_logout) actions. You attach on both of those actions functions with [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action), so they will be triggered on those events. Those functions and the `add_action` calls take place inside the *functions.php* file of your theme.

So inside *functions.php*, add this to set the cookie on login (for admin only):

```
add_action('wp_login', 'add_custom_cookie_admin');
function add_custom_cookie_admin() {
  if(current_user_can('update_core')) {
    setcookie('your_cookie_name', 'cookie value', time() + 86400, '/'); // expire in a day
  }
}
```

Note that as diziaq pointed out in his answer, you was using wrong the [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function.

And to delete the cookie on log out:

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'remove_custom_cookie_admin');
function remove_custom_cookie_admin() {
  setcookie('your_cookie_name', '', time() - 3600);
}
```

Same as diziaq pointed out, you need to remove the cookie - you can't set it to `NULL`.

Comment: I was unable to set the cookie on WP 4.6.1 using the add function above. I removed the if is_admin conditional and it worked as expected.

As far as I found in my testing, the is_admin check is unnecessary; at least for my purposes. The custom cookie won't be set unless logging in is successful.

Comment: @mingala The  `is_admin` check in this answer was for a specific purpose in the scope of this question - OP was trying to detect administrator log-in actions only. If you need to catch the login for every use roles, removing the condition works.

Comment: is_admin does not check if the user is an administrator. It checks if you are on wp-admin backend. If you have admins to be redirected to frontend upon login, is_admin will return false even if an admin user logged in. Additionally, is_admin can also check to true in the frontend if wp-admin ajax is being used, even if you are not in wp-admin backend.

Comment: To check for admin user you can do something like current_user_can( 'manage_options' )

Comment: @Tami You're right I changed it to `current_user_can('update_core')`

Answer (score 2):

Please read docs for `setcookie` function - you use it wrong. The fourth parameter must be a `string` (but you're passing a `bool`).

1. To set a cookie:

   `setcookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", time() + 600, '/');`
2. To delete the cookie you have to **set expiration date in the past**.

   `setcookie("cookieName", "anyValue", time() - 1, '/');`

Your intention to set `null` to a cookie is unreachable, because by definition the value of a cookie is a string. It can be empty, but it cannot be undefined or null.