# How to limit file download bandwidth based on cookies

Tags: apache, cookies, apache-modules, trafficshaping

I want to create premium membership plans in my wordpress site in a way that for example gold users can download files without any limits but regular users have to download files at maximum 200KB/s speed.

It's simple to save a cookie when user logins in wordpress (using `setcookie()` function according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256109/set-cookie-before-log-out-and-after-admin-login)), So it seems best way to achieve my goal is to filter users based on cookie.

I've searched and found `mod_qos` apache module, It can limit bandwidth and  has a [Privileged Users](http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/#privilegedusers) option but I don't know how to use it to exclude premium users from limitations. Provided docs are not detailed enough.

There are other modules like `mod_cband` and `mod_ratelimit` and others but none of them can filter users based on cookie (or at least I couldn't figure out a way to do so)

Other workaround is to filter users based on IP and use `tc` and `iptables` to limit bandwidth (like its done for open vpn [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/777875/how-to-do-traffic-shaping-rate-limiting-with-tc-per-openvpn-client)). But it seems difficult because you must execute shell commands for every user login and add user IP to high bandwidth group.

Note: I have two seperate servers, one is a web host with cpanel which my wordpress site runs on and other is a vps which I host my files.

Excuse my bad english or diction, this is my first question in stackoverflow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After more research I have found the solution myself:

```
<IfModule mod_qos.c>
SetEnvIf        Cookie  "foo=bar"    IsVIP
QS_EventKBytesPerSecLimit !IsVIP 200
</IfModule>
```

First line checks if a cookie named "foo" with the value "bar" exists, if so toggles environment variable "IsVIP".
Second line applies download speed limit if "IsVIP" has not set to true.

sources:

https://sourceforge.net/p/mod-qos/discussion/697421/thread/82a85ab2

https://serverfault.com/questions/541458/how-do-you-use-apache-setenvif-with-cookie-values

http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/